# How to fill CSV Data Set Config dynamically before running test?

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

I have a page that creates bulk users in my application, and I was wondering if it's possible to use the created users and put them in my users.csv file (CSV Data Set Config element) so that I will use those users in the current test only.

The idea is to have dynamic users.csv file each test instead of fixed one, for all concurrent tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do in the current test - But in a different thread group when you run consecutively.

Use BeanShell PostProcessor to write the created users in a CSV file as given below in the Thread Group 1.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

f = new FileOutputStream("CSV file Path.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
p.println(vars.get("username") + "," + vars.get("password"));
p.close();
f.close();
```

Then you can use CSV Data Set Config to read the same file and get the User Name , Password in the Next Thread Group.

If you want to use it in the same Thread Group, You can write in the CSV file - but use vars.get("username"), vars.get("password") in your test - as you can not read the CSV file yet to be created using CSV Data Set Config.

Comment: how can i set the csv file path to be the same directory of the test case file ? since i am going to use blazemeter for the test and i can't set physical file path for blazemter.

Comment: new FileOutputStream("filename.csv", true); ..it will create the csv file where u have your jmx file.